# Unable to add category and products in magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I am unable to add/save categories and products the save/save and continue edit button are unclickable .
I have double checked the file folder permission on host (644 and 755)
I am using godaddy(linux)
Here is my browser's console 
[image: Console errors]

Comment: did you checked browsers console ? is any js errors ? or is any log errors related to these under vr/log folder ?

Comment: @babyinMagento Please look at the updated question.
There are some errors.

Comment: can you copy the missing files to those paths. did you recently installed any modules, if so try disabling those modules and check.....

Comment: I changed the permission of each and every folder and file in js folder to 755
That resolved the issue to some extent .
Is it safe to do that ?

Comment: these [link1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/file-and-folder-permissions-for-magento-setup) , [link2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19205/is-it-correct-to-change-all-magento-folders-permission-to-755-and-all-files-to-6) , [link3](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html) will give answer for that, now is `save` button working ?

Comment: save button is working but photo uploader is not working

Comment: that is may be because of there is no flash software installed in browser, try in different browser or install `adobe flash player`....

Comment: I am using Google chrome v52. Flash is enabled

Comment: is `upload image` button is missing ? did you tried with other browsers also ?

Comment: i changed the permission of uploader.swf in skin/admintml/default/default/media and how it seem to work finr

Comment: the answer is wrong

Comment: you can post your own answer in detail as by saying `permissions issues` fixed for you

Comment: please check out my other question 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135550/how-can-i-change-file-and-folder-permission-in-one-go-in-godaddy-hosting

Answer (score 1):

Some times this may cause due to old (not latest version) browsers.

Example :

1. Unable to see the (browse) Buttons.
2. Button can not be clickable.
   [image]

Try to upgrade your browser or try with new browser.

Comment: I am using google chrome (latest version)

Comment: Some plug in (flash) may miss, check with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Setting appropriate file and folder permission (`755` in my case ) solved the issue.
i changed the permission of uploader.swf in skin/admintml/default/default/media to `755`