# How can i change file and folder permission in one go in godaddy hosting?

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard, file-permissions

I am facing a lot of issues due to file and folder permission in magento 1.9.2.1 
What should be the file and folder permission codes.I am using `755`for most.
Is there any way of changing the file and folder permission of all the files in one go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento default File Permission is below Just connect with your ssh access and write below command one by one

Magento File permissions:

1) `chmod -R 644 ./*`

2)`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

3)`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

4)`chmod 550 ./mage`

Answer (score 0):

you can try with ssh access
[GoDaddy ssh access shared hosting](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-your-server-or-shared-hosting-account-with-ssh-4943)

once you connect to your server use chmod command, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod