# installation problem, magento 1.9.2 BLANK PAGE

Tags: installation

i am trying to install magento 1.9.2 on **cpanel (/public_html)**
 but page `xyz.com/index.php/install/`       is blank.

please let me know what folder and file needs to be changed or anything ?

please advise so i can run installation.

Comment: problem in permission of folders

Comment: what should i do now ? i am new in magento.  Which file and folder i should need to change the permission and how ?

Comment: permission set below type using c-panel
`files: 644,
folders: 755,   
Media & Var: 777    `

Comment: any particular file needs to change the permission ??

Comment: no root files change permission

Comment: thanks fo ryour quick reply. as i told you  i am quite new user. i don;t know anything but trying to install.  therefore you are requested to help me in steps.

Answer (score 0):

run the following command

```
sudo find /var/www/baseMagentoDirectory/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/baseMagentoDirectory/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you put below code in the top of yours Magento root directory **index.php** file.

   `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

This will display the exact error you have in the browser. Most probably you will get Forbidden Access (Permission issue).

2. Then connect your cpanel with the SSH access. [Steps here](https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-your-account-using-putty)
3. Now all files need to give permission 644 and folders need 755. [Steps here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135550/how-can-i-change-file-and-folder-permission-in-one-go-in-godaddy-hosting)
4. Clear browser caches and reload.